# When does a thread become idle?

Tags: java, multithreading

What do we mean by an idle thread? And when does it occur? 
Context : ThreadPoolExecutor - it says even if there is an idle thread, if the corePoolSize is small, a new thread is created

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context an idle thread is one that is owned/held by the ThreadPoolExecutor and is not currently running any Runnable/Callable.

When work is submitted to the TPE, and if an idle thread is chosen, then it becomes active and runs the Runnable/Callable. Once the Runnable/Callable completes the thread goes back to being idle (but may immediately become active again if there is more work to do and the TPE choses to use that now available thread).

Comment: Hmm does this mean that the thread does not die at all? I was wondering once the thread executes (the run() method), the thread dies and a new thread is created

Comment: @UserInteractive - if the thread died, it would not be a pool thread!  'once the thread executes (the run() method), the thread dies' - sure, so, in pool threads, the run() method never returns - it has an infinite loop in it that blocks at the top on the pool queue synchro.

Answer (score 2):

it simply means when ThreadPool does not have any task to be executed or has more active threads than tasks available, then the excess thread go idle. It means they simply are not available to the scheduler (aka in sleep state).

Answer (score 2):

Well in the context of the thread pool it means that it is created but it is not started; is waiting for jobs to start. What it means there there is that even if there are more threads than needed jobs new threads might be created, not to reach the case when a new job is needed to be submitted but there aren't threads available. Of course this goes up to a limit; also it depends on configuration.

Answer (score 2):

**What do we mean by an idle thread?**

Idle thread : Worker threads are idle, if they are not running any tasks.

**When does it occur?**

When a thread has finish executing current task or not has any task to run, it becomes idle.

**corePoolSize :**
To keep atleast these many threads available for processing tasks. It reduces waiting time for the initial set of tasks, when the corePoolSize threads are idle or if corePoolSize limit has not been reached

> Core and maximum pool sizes:
>
> A ThreadPoolExecutor will automatically adjust the pool size (see getPoolSize()) according to the bounds set by corePoolSize (see getCorePoolSize()) and maximumPoolSize (see getMaximumPoolSize()). When a new task is submitted in method execute(java.lang.Runnable), and fewer than corePoolSize threads are running, a new thread is created to handle the request, even if other worker threads are idle. If there are more than corePoolSize but less than maximumPoolSize threads running, a new thread will be created only if the queue is full. By setting corePoolSize and maximumPoolSize the same, you create a fixed-size thread pool. By setting maximumPoolSize to an essentially unbounded value such as Integer.MAX_VALUE, you allow the pool to accommodate an arbitrary number of concurrent tasks. Most typically, core and maximum pool sizes are set only upon construction, but they may also be changed dynamically using setCorePoolSize(int) and setMaximumPoolSize(int).